# Inverse Matrix - abstract represention

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I should find the inverse matrix for this:

[image]

But how to interpret this one? How to interpret the dots etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general convention. If the pattern could be understood, then dots symbolize the continuation of the pattern.

This pattern:

Note there is **exactly** one non zero element namely $a_{i, n-i+1}$, where $a_{i,j}$ is the element in $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. All other elements are $0$s.

Comment: Thanks, so should I just try to compute it like "normal" inverse matrix?

Comment: Unless you were asked to compute the *abnormal* inverse

Comment: This is simple, due to a very specific form of the matrix. Multiplying first row of given matrix by the first column of the inverse should give you $1$. And by any other column $0$, so you can establish what is the last row of the inverse matrix. Proceed to the second row. It's like mirroring and inverting elements on the diagonal

Comment: Thanks! So basically just mirroring this matrice is probably enough for the solution...